# How does 'Agent Doe' end up where he does in Predestination?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, predestination

In the movie *Predestination*, one of the pre-climax scenes shows that the barkeep (Agent Doe) turns into the Fizzle Bomber by killing his future self.

This is described in the timeline on the main wikipedia article for the movie -
[1975-Mar-06: Agent Doe kills the Fizzle Bomber, his future self, thus becoming the Fizzle Bomber.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film))

But Agent Doe is the one who actually tries to disarm the bombs and save lives.

**How does a guy such as him (who saves lives) turn into the Fizzle bomber (who takes lives)?**

Comment: This is explained at the link you gave - *"The Fizzle Bomber turns out to be the agent's own future self, **now suffering from psychosis** as a result of excessive time travel. "*

Comment: @Paulie_D You mean, he turned into Fizzle bomber because he is suffering from psychosis as a result of excessive time travel?

Comment: Please comment some explanation while down voting. It helps a beginner like me to ask questions properly.

Comment: Yes, basically, too much time travel made him insane.

Comment: Took a stab at editing the title to remove the major spoiler from it. There might be a better wording that still keeps the question the same.

Answer (score 2):

ref : [Predestination Explained](https://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2015/9/18/Predestination-2014-Plot-Explained)

> Barkeep has been basically chasing his own self from a future time.
>   The time leaps have caused Barkeep to grow maniacal and turn into the
>   Fizzle bomber.
>
> Barkeep does not report the time device which he’s unable to
>   decommission. This indicates that he continues to use the device; time
>   jumps are indicated to have an effect on the mind. Let’s not forget
>   about the fact that every other event in this story is predestined to
>   happen. This should be no exception to the rule. It only makes sense
>   that Barkeep grows old to become the insane Fizzle bomber.

Though the temporal agent has been disarming bombs, he doesn't know that his future self is the one planting them. This is why they refer to it as a snake eating its own tail.

Finally at the laundromat .. the barkeep comes to know that the fizzle bomber is merely an older version of himself. All this time he has loathed the fizzle bomber only to find out that it is his future self. While the fizzle bomber says that killing him is what will cause the barkeep to start a journey that ends up with him being the fizzle bomber .. the barkeep is unable to see past his hatred for the fizzle bomber (even though it is his future self). In his hated and anger he kills his future self.

After this, we are shown that his machine doesn't deactivate. He doesn't report it either. At this point the barkeep is not insane. He going to start using the time machine to prevent himself from becoming the fizzle bomber. But the very act of him doing so will result in his insanity and hence become the fizzle bomber years later.